# message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members returns some members and sometimes none at all

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I used message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members to get the members that have a role but I only get some of them or it only returns a member if I have the role here's my code

```
 let roleId = "812004859439218758"
                const valorantRosterMsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle ("Valorant Roster") 
                .setDescription (msg.guild.roles.cache.get(roleId).members.map(m=>m.user).join('\n'))
                 msg.channel.send(valorantRosterMsg)
```

Comment: Dinty's answer solved the issue. Just make sure to re-invite the discord bot to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is that you haven't enabled the server members intent, which is required to get a full list of members. You can do so here on your bot page:

[image]

Comment: i will but it does not return offline members

Answer (score 0):

put in your code

```
msg.guild.members.fetch()
```